# MsgBox to enable/disable announcements of words you filled in the inputbox

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox, msgbox

Hey so I'm making a code so you can search words in a specific folder, and after you filled in the folder path, it messages you: "You filled in *C:\Yes\Test*", i want to have a Message box to enable / disable the announcement. I have this but it gives me the error: Else without if. i think its because in the code it states end if 2x before really ending it. (BTW its in dutch)

````
antwoord = MsgBox("Wilt u meldingen ontvangen van het invullen van folderpad & woord", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Meldingen")
    If antwoord = vbYes Then
    strPath = Application.InputBox("Folderpad. 'bijvoorbeeld: (C:\Users\voor\beeld\WoordenZoeker)'                                                                                     ", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Je hebt niks ingevuld", vbCritical
Else
    MsgBox "Je hebt " & strPath & " " & "ingevoerd."
End If
    strSearch = Application.InputBox("Woord", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Je hebt niks ingevuld", vbCritical
Else
    MsgBox "Je hebt " & strSearch & " " & "ingevoerd."
    If antwoord = vbNo Then
    strPath = Application.InputBox("Folderpad. 'bijvoorbeeld: (C:\Users\voor\beeld\WoordenZoeker)'                                                                                     ", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    End If
    strSearch = Application.InputBox("Woord", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
End If```
````

Comment: Without indentation you cannot understand anything from your code. After formatting it a little it looks obvious that you missed two `End If`. One after `MsgBox "Je hebt " & strSearch & " " & "ingevoerd."` and the second one at the end...

Comment: @FanaDuru Hey thanks, i works half now.... When i press Yes it Does it all 2x and when i press No it doesn't do anything

Comment: Where do you press "Yes" and "No"? I do not see any MsgBox to present these two options... I checked the code only for solving your `End If` missing. Would you like your MsgBox to present "Yes/No" options? If yes, where this type of MsgBox to appear? I do not understand what your code messages means. Dutch is not so friendly for me... :)

Comment: @FanaDuru sorry forget it

Comment: What did you forget?

Comment: @FanaDuru the Messagebox statement, its there now

Comment: I cannot explain in a comment what I suppose is good to do... I will post an answer.

Comment: Alright! You send this

Answer (score 0):

Try the next way, please. I do not understand the messages and what exactly you want doing... This code presents the first MsgBox offering the possibility to choose between Yes and No. If you press Yes, The InputBox will appear. If you do not enter anything, a MsgBox will say 'something'. Then the code continues with the next lines. If you want it to stop in some circumstances, tell us where, please:

```
antwoord = MsgBox("Wilt u meldingen ontvangen van het invullen van folderpad & woord", _
                                    vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Meldingen")
    If antwoord = vbYes Then
        strPath = Application.InputBox("Folderpad. 'bijvoorbeeld: (C:\Users\voor\beeld\WoordenZoeker)'                                                                                     ", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
        If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Je hebt niks ingevuld", vbCritical
        Else
            MsgBox "you entered """ & strPath & """."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Je hebt " & strPath & " " & "ingevoerd."
        Exit Sub 'The code stops here
    End If
    strSearch = Application.InputBox("Woord", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Je hebt niks ingevuld", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "Je hebt " & strSearch & " " & "ingevoerd."
        If antwoord = vbNo Then
            strPath = Application.InputBox("Folderpad. 'bijvoorbeeld: (C:\Users\voor\beeld\WoordenZoeker)'                                                                                     ", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
        End If
        strSearch = Application.InputBox("Woord", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    End If
```

Comment: I send you the older english version

Comment: @FanaDunu do you by any chance have something like Discord, Skype etc?

Comment: S3M: No need to have any of them if you cannot explain which is your need...

Comment: @FanaDuru thats why a call would be nice, so i can explain.

Comment: @FanaDuru ok... Well I'll just scrap that then... Doing this for my grandfather

Comment: What does the above code do and you do not like that? Did you read what I wrote before the code?

Comment: Oh sorry, Well if you press Yes it needs to open Inputbox with FolderPad first and when you enter "C:\Test" it gives you a message with: "You entered C:\Test". And if you press no it needs to open Inputbox with FolderPad first but not give the You entered C:\Test / the string

Comment: S3M: Test it now, please. It sends also the confirmation about the path and it stops if Yes has not been pressed. Is that what you want? It is late in my country and I must close my laptop in some minutes...

Comment: @FanaDuru now it still does 2x Word if i press Yes, and when i press No it only says "Je hebt  ingevuld" (You have entered (blank))

Comment: @S3M: Sorry, I must close my laptop. I cannot work blind, not understanding the messages signification... I would suggest you to translate them and If not too late, I will look tomorrow on your updated code...

Answer (score 0):

```
strPath = Application.InputBox("Directory. 'example: (C:\Users\ex\ample\WordSearcher)'                                                                                     ", "WordSearcher by S3M")
    If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
         MsgBox "You have not entered anything", vbCritical
    Else
         MsgBox "You entered" & " " & strPath
   End If
    strSearch = Application.InputBox("Word", "WordSearcher by S3M")
    If Len(strSearch) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You have not entered anything", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "You entered" & " " & strSearch
    End If
```

Comment: And what still happens with current version, if i press yes it opens application.inputbox(FilePath) then 2x application.inputbox(word), but its only ment to do 1x application.inputbox(word). And same for No now

Comment: What? do you by any chance have something like Discord, Skype etc?

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru here is the translated code, is there i way i can send the whole code to you privately?

```
 anwser = MsgBox("Would you like to recieve notifications from the value of folderpath and word", _
                                    vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Notifications")
    If anwser = vbYes Then
        strPath = Application.InputBox("Folderpath. 'example: (C:\Users\voor\beeld\WoordenZoeker)'          ", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
        If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You did not enter anything", vbCritical
        Else
            MsgBox "You have entered" & " " & strPath
        End If
        strSearch = Application.InputBox("Word", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
        If Len(strPath) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You have not entered anything", vbCritical
        Else
            MsgBox "You have entered" & " " & strSearch
         Exit Sub 'The code stops here
    End If
        If anwser = vbNo Then
            strPath = Application.InputBox("Folderpath. 'example: (C:\Users\voor\beeld\WoordenZoeker)'                   ", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    End If
            strSearch = Application.InputBox("Word", "WoordenZoeker door S3M")
    End If
```